# Load BitmapImage into WriteableBitmap but no method existing

Tags: c#, bitmap, windows-8.1, blur, writeablebitmap

The constructor of `WriteableBitmap` class with Windows 8 only takes two arguments: the height and the width of this object. Meanwhile with Silverlight it accepts a `BitmapImage` object as argument. (Verified on MSDN : [WriteableBitmap.WriteableBitmap constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br243263))

I would like to load this `BitmapImage` because I'm trying to blur an image which already exists on my Assets folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your help, I succeed to blur my image. Here is the sample in order to link the BitmapImage into the WriteableBitmap object :

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filename, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bi.PixelWidth, bi.PixelHeight);

var streamFile = await GetFileStream(myFile);
await wb.SetSourceAsync(streamFile);
wb = wb.Convolute(WriteableBitmapExtensions.KernelGaussianBlur5x5);
```

Then just write the WriteableBitmap into the LocalStorage !

Comment: GetFileStream is not found?!?!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to load a BitmapImage into WritableBitmap like this:

```
WriteableBitmap writableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage);
```

See here [WriteableBitmap Constructor (BitmapSource)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa346377%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I saw everywhere this but I don't have access to System.Windows.Media.Imaging but to Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging (I'm on Windows 8 RT, no Windows Phone 8.1) ...

Comment: This page indicates you'll have to use the `SetSource` or `SetSourceAsync` method for that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/dn263229.aspx

Comment: If you have access to the file itself, you could load it directly like this: 
`using (var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
{
    WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height);
    await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream);
}`