# Bitmap to WriteableBitmap C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bitmap, writeablebitmap, writeablebitmapex

Hi guys I'm trying to get a pixel value from an image taken using a windows phone camera. But it seems as though I am creating an empty writeable bitmap instead of converting the photo loaded into a writeable bitmap. I'm a beginner with c#. Any ideas on where I am going wrong? code is below, thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
//using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Pickers;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.Storage.Streams; // for opening image file
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using Windows.Graphics;
using Windows.Graphics.Imaging;


// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=391641

namespace Colour_Find
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, IFileOpenPickerContinuable  // IFileOpenPickerContinuable
    {

        // global memory for image manipulation
        WriteableBitmap originalImage;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
        /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Prepare page for display here.

            // TODO: If your application contains multiple pages, ensure that you are
            // handling the hardware Back button by registering for the
            // Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed event.
            // If you are using the NavigationHelper provided by some templates,
            // this event is handled for you.
        }
        private void PickAFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  // Lee
        {

            FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
            openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
            // Launch file open picker and caller app is suspended 
            // and may be terminated if required
            openPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();


        }


        public async void ContinueFileOpenPicker(FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs args)
        {
            StorageFile file = args.Files[0]; // get picked filename
            outputTextBlock.Text = file.Name; // show filename

            if (file != null)
            {
                // Open a stream for the selected file.
                IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenReadAsync();

                // Set the image source to the selected bitmap.
                BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.SetSource(fileStream);
                pictureBox.Source = bitmapImage;
            }


        }

        public async void GetPixel(Image pictureBox)
        {


            WriteableBitmap modifiedImage = pictureBox.Source as WriteableBitmap;
            if (modifiedImage == null)
            {
                BitmapSource bs = pictureBox.Source as BitmapSource;
                modifiedImage = new WriteableBitmap(bs.PixelWidth, bs.PixelHeight);
            }




                    Color pixelColor = modifiedImage.GetPixel(300,300);
                    string myString = pixelColor.ToString();
                    TextBlock1.Text = myString;

        }

        private void GetPixelBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            GetPixel(pictureBox);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: All I see in the code you posted is one place where you create a `BitmapImage` for use as the `Source` for your `PictureBox` control, and then another place where if the `Source` object is not a `WriteableBitmap` object (which `BitmapImage` is _not_), you create a brand new, empty `WriteableBitmap`. In other words, the code you posted seems entirely consistent with, and in a painfully obvious way, your problem description. It's not clear what specifically you are having trouble with. Why did you expect this code to work in the first place?

Comment: @PeterDuniho ahh thank you so much! I should've really figured to be honest!

Answer (score 0):

See:https://stackoverflow.com/a/23287765/6116637

And change the GetPixel

```
   public async void GetPixel(Image pictureBox)
    {


        WriteableBitmap modifiedImage = pictureBox.Source as WriteableBitmap;
        if (modifiedImage == null)
        {
            BitmapSource bs = pictureBox.Source as BitmapSource;
            modifiedImage = new WriteableBitmap(bs);

        }




                Color pixelColor = modifiedImage.GetPixel(300,300);
                string myString = pixelColor.ToString();
                TextBlock1.Text = myString;

    }
```